# @SQLInsert How to automatically insert all fields?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using @SQLInsert(sql="INSERT IGNORE into data (code, file_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)) for ignoring DataIntegrityExceptions while batch saving into the data table. The problem is that my data table has more than 30 columns and schema could update in future. It is hard to maintain the insert statement consistent to the schema. How can I write a generic insert statement inside @SQLInsert that takes care of all the columns and I don't have to explicitly write each column name and value in the sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of @sqlInsert I used namedjdbctemplate with SqlParameterSource
and generated sql from reflection

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class clazz = getDataClass();
    while (clazz != Object.class) {
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                namesList.add(field.getName().replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z]+)", "$1_$2").toLowerCase());
                valueList.add(":" + field.getName());
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }

    this.insertSql = "insert ignore into " + getTableName() + "(" + String.join(",", namesList) + ") VALUES("
            + String.join(",", valueList) + ")";
```

then

```
for (T data : temp) {
        data.setId(randomId);
    }
    SqlParameterSource[] batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(temp.toArray());
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSql, batch);
```

I am using @column annotation above all fields that I want to insert

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You will have to list out all columns in the order Hibernate expects it. What you could do though is generate the insert statement in a `MetadataContributor` for every `PersistentClass` you care about.